# Problem with deploying contract on BSC Test net

Tags: solidity, remix, bsc

I'm new here. I want to deploy a contract on the BSC test net thru remix. The code is below. I'm running into a problem "This contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent's methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly."

```
abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address payable) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes memory) {
        this;
        return msg.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the abstract keywork. You have declared it as  an abstract contract.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, you should mark the functions in the Context contract as virtual and remove their implementations. Then, in child contracts that inherit from Context, you'll need to override these functions and provide the implementations. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
// Abstract Context contract
abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address payable);

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes memory);
}

// Concrete implementation of Context
contract ConcreteContext is Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual override returns (address payable) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual override returns (bytes memory) {
        this;
        return msg.data;
    }
}

// Your contract inheriting from ConcreteContext
contract YourContract is ConcreteContext {
    // Your contract's logic here...
}
```